# Microsoft Azure Speech SDK - Disable Audio Logging

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, microsoft-speech-api, azure-speech

I am trying to use Microsoft Azure Speech to text service. I have a working example using the Python Quickstarts. But I am wondering if Microsoft saves the audio files and if there is anyway to opt-out of it? Any thoughts will be much appreciated.

I did find this property inside of the Speech SDk Azure speech SpeechServiceConnection_EnableAudioLogging - but I am not sure how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Logging to file is an optional feature for the Speech SDK. During development logging provides additional information and diagnostics from the Speech SDK's core components. It can be enabled by setting the property Speech_LogFilename on a speech configuration object to the location and name of the log file. Logging will be activated globally once a recognizer is created from that configuration and can't be disabled afterwards.

The log file name is specified on a configuration object. Taking the SpeechConfig as an example and assuming that you have created an instance called config:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SpeechServiceConnection_EnableAudioLogging is not enabled by default, so unless you enable it, your audio is not stored in the service side. If you decide to enable the property, the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk/propertyid?view=azure-node-latest, describes more details on how long audio is stored for example.